# Data validation in server by socket.io and node.js then POST a from

Tags: node.js, post, socket.io

I have a form like this:

```
<form method='post' action='next' onsubmit="return validateMyForm();" >
    <input type="text" id="data" />
<input type="submit" />
<p id="result"></p>
```

and this code for interact with node.js:

```
socket = io.connect();
function vlidateMyForm(){
    var data = $('data').val();
    socket.emit('login',{data: data});   // check dataBase in server
    return false;
}

socket.on('responseLogin',function(result){
    if(result){    // if data is valid 
        // submit form  
    }
    else{   // data invalid
        $('#result').html('field is not valid')
    }  
});
```

I want to submit my form, when the result is true. What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Change `socket.on('responseLogin',function(result){...` to `socket.on('login',function(result){...` should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) to submit the form :

```
$("form#formID").submit();
```

Your form must have [action](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) attribute like `action='url_to_post_to'` for this.

Or if you like to use AJAX so that you can process the data, you can do :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'url_to_post_to',
    data: $("#formID").serialize(),
    success: function(data)
    {
       alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: In that case you can try `socket.emit('form',$("#formID").serialize())`. Tell if it works.

Comment: thank's friend. not works. it's not my problem. the validateMyForm() return false so this form are not submit. i want when responseLogin data is true form to submit. thank's a lot again